# Mask out ROI without changing the image size

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I got some image of a cattle farm. Each image supposes to cover only two pen (small cattle room). However, the camera also covers neighboring pens. I need to get rid of the areas of the neighboring pens.

Input Image -

[image: enter image here]

The Output image -

[image: enter image here]

I have tried the following command and it does the job. However, it shrinks the size of the image and makes the output of the size of the bounding box generated in line 2. The output becomes smaller than the original image. In this case, the original image is 2560x1440 but the output is 2536x1406.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

frame = cv2.imread("input.jpg")
# pts - location of the 4 corners of the roi
pts = np.array([[6, 1425],[953, 20 ],[1934, 40 ], [2541,1340]])
rect = cv2.boundingRect(pts)
x, y, w, h = rect
croped = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w].copy()
pts = pts - pts.min(axis=0)
mask = np.zeros(croped.shape[:2], np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [pts], -1, (255, 255, 255), -1, cv2.LINE_AA)
frame_roi = cv2.bitwise_and(croped, croped, mask=mask)
cv2.imwrite("output.jpg", frame_roi)
```

However, I need the output image to be the same size as the input image and anything out of the ROI to be black/white (shown below, it's a different picture though). Both the white or black masked region will work (the above output has black and hand edited image below has white).  Is there a way of doing that with opencv or any other library?

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the image at its original size? Here is downsampled to 640x360, and your code obviously can't work on it.

Comment: @Paul92 I have edited the codes a little and tested on an image then uploaded the results here. Please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The error was in this line

```
mask = np.zeros(croped.shape[:2], np.uint8)
```

which should be the exact same size as your original/input image. So changing that to the original shape should give the correct output image.

```
mask = np.zeros(original_image.shape, np.uint8)
```

Here's the shape of the output image

> (1440L, 2560L, 3L)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

original_frame = cv2.imread("1.jpg")
frame = original_frame.copy()

# pts - location of the 4 corners of the roi
pts = np.array([[6, 1425],[953, 20],[1934, 40], [2541,1340]])
(x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(pts)

pts = pts - pts.min(axis=0)
mask = np.zeros(original_frame.shape, np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [pts], -1, (255, 255, 255), -1, cv2.LINE_AA)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(original_frame, mask)

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imwrite('result.png', result)
print(result.shape)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```